# PHP namespace & constructor issues

Tags: php, constructor, namespaces

I am trying the following :

```
//file1.
namespace foo;
class mine {
     public function mine() {
         echo "Does not work!!";
     } 
}
//file2. 

use foo/mine;
include "foo/mine.php";
$obj = new mine();
```

the above scenario is not working. No errors including the file -- constructor does not get called.

However when i use __constructor(), everything works fine. I am using php v5.4

Answer (score 6):

From [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
>   function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
>   parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
>   by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case
>   that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method
>   named __construct() which was used for different semantics.
>
> As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a
>   namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This
>   change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

You can use the name of the class as constructor (unless the class is namespaced) because PHP5 keeps this for backwards compatibility with PHP4, but this is not recomended because it is the old way and may be removed in newer versions of php. So unless you are writting something that needs for some reason to be PHP4 compatible use `__construct()`.

Answer (score 1):

Below are 2 different possible solutions to the namespace\constructor problem

```
//parentclass.php
class parentclass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //by default, strip the namespace from class name
    //then attempt to call the constructor
    call_user_func_array([$this,end(explode("\\",get_class($this)))],func_get_args());
  }
}

//foo/bar.php
namespace foo;
class bar extends \parentclass
{
  public function bar($qaz,$wsx)
  {
  //...
  }
}

$abc = new foo\bar(1,2);
```

and

```
//parentclass.php
class parentclass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //by default, replace the namespace separator (\) with an underscore (_)
    //then attempt to call the constructor
    call_user_func_array([$this,preg_replace("/\\/","_",get_class($this))],func_get_args());
  }
}

//foo/bar.php
namespace foo;
class bar extends \parentclass
{
  public function foo_bar($qaz,$wsx)
  {
  //...
  }
}

$abc = new foo\bar(1,2);
```